# Data Explorer not running any queries for my UserID

Tags: support, data-explorer

Hey all, odd problem here. Upon discovering the Data Explorer yesterday, I sat down in my chair and prepared myself for a couple of hours of Sunday time wasting. To my dismay, as I tried one query after another, I found that my UserId (161176) simply never returned anything for any query.

I thought the problem might lie with Google Chrome, somehow, but I'm getting great results for any number of other random users whose IDs I've tried. Is this a known bug? Any recommendations on how to start exploring data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look on the [Data Explorer homepage](http://odata.stackexchange.com/), you can see that the last time it was updated was with the October 30 data dump. Anything after that date is not reflected. (However, they're working on the November data dump currently). Since most of your activity was after that date, it's currently not available yet.

I do see one post by you in [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/15859/), made in August of last year.

Comment: Ah, that's excellent, thanks a lot! Should've looked closer at the home page. I'll hit the check when I'm allowed, in three minutes.